# How is it possible the class inheritance in namespaces using Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, inheritance, namespaces

In my RoR3 application I have a namespace called NS1 so that I have this filesystem structure:

```
ROOT_RAILS/controllers/
ROOT_RAILS/controllers/application_controller.rb
ROOT_RAILS/controllers/ns/
ROOT_RAILS/controllers/ns/ns_controller.rb
ROOT_RAILS/controllers/ns/profiles_controller.rb
```

I would like that 'ns_controller.rb' inherits from application controller, so in 'ns_controller.rb' file I have:

```
class Ns::NsController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Is this the right approach? Anyway if I am in this situation...

---

In `ROOT_RAILS/config/routes.rb` I have:

```
namespace "ns" do
  resources :profiles
end
```

`@profile` is a ActiveRecord:

```
@profile.find(1).name
=> "Ruby on"
@profile.find(1).surname
=> "Rails"
```

In `application_controller.rb` I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  @profile = Profile.find(1)
end
```

In `ns_controller.rb` I have:

```
class Ns::NsController < ApplicationController
  @name = @profile.name
  @surname = @profile.surname
end
```

---

... `@name` and `@surname` variables are not set. **Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's some code you're not showing here, you're trying to set an instance variable in a class body rather than an instance method, which means the variable won't be available in controller actions (which are instance methods).

If you want find method that can be inherited, you could do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def load_profile
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end
end

class Ns::NsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_profile

  def show
    # @profile assigned a value in load_profile
  end
end
```